# Why does a variable assigned by value to an array element (after an earlier assign-by-reference) change when the array element is changed?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

When I run the code blow:

```
$var[0] = 'a';
$tmp = $var;
$var[0] = 'b';
var_dump($tmp);
```

the output is:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "a" }
```

When I add a line as follows:

```
$var[0] = 'a';
$foo = & $var[0]; # added line
$tmp = $var;
$var[0] = 'b';
var_dump($tmp);
```

the output becomes:

```
array(1) { [0]=> &string(1) "b" }
```

If I assign a variable `$foo` by reference to an array's element `$var[0]`, is the variable `$tmp` assigned by value to the array `$var` supposed to change like that? Why does this happen?

Comment: Note that the various "pass-by-*" terms only apply to function arguments. There's no variable passing here, only assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I have not been able to find an explicit reference for this, so I'm mostly inferring here.

A regular reference works through the symbol table. When creating a variable and a value, both are stored in the local symbol table like so:

```
$foo = "bar";

+--------+-------+
| symbol | value |
+--------+-------+
| $foo   | "bar" |
+--------+-------+
```

When a reference is created, this simply adds another symbol for the same value to the table:

```
$bar =& $foo;

+------------+-------+
| symbol     | value |
+------------+-------+
| $foo, $bar | "bar" |
+------------+-------+
```

Array keys are stored differently though:

```
$var[0] = 'a';

+--------+-----------------+
| symbol | value           |
+--------+-----------------+
| $var   | array(0 => 'a') |
+--------+-----------------+
```

There's an entry in the symbol table for `$var`, but the values inside the array are not individually referenced in the symbol table. What I infer must be happening when creating a reference to the value `'a'` (stored in `$var[0]`) is that the value `'a'` is separated from the array `$var` and `$var[0]` itself becomes a reference to the new location of where `'a'` is stored:

```
$foo =& $var[0];

+--------+------------------+
| symbol | value            |
+--------+------------------+
| $var   | array(0 => %REF) |
| $foo   | %REF             |
| %REF   | 'a'              |
+--------+------------------+
```

I guess that the internal implementation of the symbol table does not allow to create direct references to array keys, therefore this is the only way to create a reference to an array element.

So when copying `$var` to `$tmp`, the reference is copied with it:

```
$tmp = $var;

+--------+------------------+
| symbol | value            |
+--------+------------------+
| $var   | array(0 => %REF) |
| $foo   | %REF             |
| %REF   | 'a'              |
| $tmp   | array(0 => %REF) |
+--------+------------------+
```

Then, when changing the value `$var[0]` refers to, it changes the value of `%REF`, which both `$tmp` and `$var` refer to.

As I said, this may or may not be an accurate explanation of what's happening internally, but it illustrates the principle.

Answer (score 2):

This is [brought up in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php), one of the [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#102123) on the page actually mention this specific behavior.